# change button colors when it's clicked on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is a builder that I will call 11 times, and I want to change the other 10 buttons color to grey when I click in one of the 11 buttons, how do I do that?

```
Widget buildElevatedButton(int number, Color buttonColor) {
 return Padding(
   padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
    child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       ElevatedButton(
         onPressed: () {},
         child: Text(
               "$number",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
         style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
           shadowColor: Colors.grey,
           primary: buttonColor,
           minimumSize: Size(70, 70),
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            ),
             textStyle: TextStyle(
             fontSize: 40,
             fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
           ),
         ),
       ),
     ],
   ),
 );
```

}

Comment: Use an inline condition statement

Comment: by checking if the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Map` for checking the state

```
Map<int, bool> buttons = {
    0: false,
    1: false,
    2: false,
    3: false,
    4: false,
  };
```

and then inside your builder when the button is clicked toggle the `Map buttons` and change state to `true`

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: buttons.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState((){
                buttons[index] = true;
              });
              buttons.forEach((k, v) {
                if(index != k){
                  buttons[k]=false;
                }
              });
            },
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: buttons[index]?MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue): MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.grey),
            ),
            child: Text(
              "Button $index",
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: thanx bro, will try it later and give you a feedback!

Comment: You didn't try it out and marked it as the answer? Don't confuse others amigo!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is a Stateless Widget class that takes a callback, which is passed to the button. The state of the buttons needs to be maintained by the root widget (you lift the state up).
The flutter documentation on state are quite good: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive

Here is a working example:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _selectedButton = null;
  void setSelectedButton(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedButton = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Wrap(children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            CustomElevatedButton(
                i,
                _selectedButton == null
                    ? Colors.red
                    : _selectedButton == i
                        ? Colors.red
                        : Colors.grey, () {
              setSelectedButton(i);
            }),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomElevatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;
  final Color buttonColor;
  final void Function() onPressed;
  CustomElevatedButton(this.number, this.buttonColor, this.onPressed);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: onPressed,
            child: Text(
              '${number + 1}',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              shadowColor: Colors.grey,
              primary: buttonColor,
              minimumSize: Size(70, 70),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              ),
              textStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 40,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Explanation: The MyHomePage stateful widget is the parent and maintains the state (i.e. it keeps track of which button is pressed). The child is a stateless widget with your custom button. The state is lifted up to the place where the buttons are actually built.

Comment: working perfectly, also the documentation was very helpfull.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer... Tested and worked perfectly. if you ever need other elaborate stuffs like that try [animated widget](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_widgets).