# How to update the colors of containers upon clicking on one of the containers

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

I am trying to change the colours of containers in a ListView builder which scrolls horizontally, below is my code. Currently I can change the color of a container to yellow but I want to click on one container and then disable the colors of the others other than changing the color of any container I tap on which results in all the containers changing at the long run.

```
Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 135,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          itemCount: 5,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                            return Preference(
                              imageName: preference[index]['imageName'],
                              title: preference[index]['title'],
                            );
                          }),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Below code is the list of Maps I used in the above code

```
List preference = [
  {
    'imageName': 'assets/icons/coffee.png',
    'title': 'Breakfast',
  },
  {
    'imageName': 'assets/icons/beverage.png',
    'title': 'Beverages',
  },
  {
    'imageName': 'assets/icons/snack.png',
    'title': 'Snacks',
  },
  {
    'imageName': 'assets/icons/pizza.png',
    'title': 'Dessert',
  },
  {
    'imageName': 'assets/icons/soup.png',
    'title': 'Soups',
  },
];
```

The final code below shows the actuall container

```
class Preference extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imageName;
  final String title;
  const Preference({
    Key? key,
    required this.imageName,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Preference> createState() => _PreferenceState();
}

class _PreferenceState extends State<Preference> {
  bool preferencePressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Ink(
              child: InkWell(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                onTap: () => setState(() {
                  preferencePressed = !preferencePressed;
                }),
                child: Image.asset(
                  widget.imageName,
                  scale: 1.5,
                ),
              ),
              //
              width: 80,
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: preferencePressed == false
                    ? const Color(0xFFf5f5f5)
                    : Colors.yellow, //,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Text(
              widget.title,
              style: constants.TextStyles.subTitle
                  .copyWith(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 25,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably you can achieve that by adding one more field to the list isActive and while building the the listview builder change the color of the the active button by setting up isActive to true and rest the other buttons by setting it to false. Here is an example that can help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69289968/9414608)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new state variable to your widget called _activeButtonIndex.

Then you can change that state by refactoring the Preference widget to make it accept an onpress callback and a boolean indicating if the widget is being active. Which means by then you can make the Preference widget stateless as the state is being lifted up to the parent.

Then in the parent's listview builder, you can do something like

```
child: ListView.builder(
 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
 itemCount: 5,
 itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
   return Preference(
     imageName: preference[index]['imageName'],
     title: preference[index]['title'],
     isActive: index == _activeButtonIndex,
     onPress: () => setState(() {  _activeButtonIndex = index; }),
    );
}),
```

By doing this, when the user press on the button, they will trigger the rebuild of the widget as we change the state, then the button that is being pressed will be highlighted.